# String arrays in Java - declaring fixed length, passing values into constructors and adding to them

Tags: java, arrays, string

So, first off, in my class Film I need to declare various fields including a string array of actors a fixed length (5). My default constructor needs to set these values for now but later I think I'll need the 5 string values to null so I can add actors up to the limit.
I then want to be able to create instances of the class using values passed to a constructor and finally add actors to the string array of a given film - where there's a free spot (and throw an exception when there's not one).

What I have so far:

```
public class Film {
    private String title;
    private String[] actors = new String[5]; // can I set the limit here and use this string below?
    private double budget;

    // default constructor:
    public Film() {
        title = "Default title";
        // This creates a new string though and doesn't limit to 5 :o(
        authors = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e"};
        budget = 1.1
    }

    // constructor which takes values passed in:
    public Film(String title, double budget, String[] actors) {
        this.title = title;
        this.budget = budget;
        this.actors = actors;
    }
}
```

In my main programme, I have the following which shows an error on the comma after the budget value and I can't work out why:

```
public class Main {

    Film homeAlone = new Film("Home Alone", 10.9, ("McCauley", "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"));

}
```

And as for the 'adding an actor' method - I don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: The syntax for passing an array is `new String[]{"McCauley", "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"}`

Comment: ...and also you don't have the variable authors.

Comment: `budget = 1.1` missing semicolon after definition

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing the array in this line

```
private String[] actors = new String[5];
```

and again in this line

```
authors = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e"};
```

The first statement created an empty array of length 5 and it does restrict it to 5 elements. If you write below statements, it will throw an exception because array created has 5 bins only 0...4 and can hold only 5 elements

```
private String[] actors = new String[5];
actors[5]="John";
```

But again when you wrote the second statement you have reinitialized the previous array to 6 elements by passing 6 elements in the constructor itself and it created a new array of length 6 having those 6 elements you passed in the constructor.

Now again if you want to execute statement below it will throw an exception.

```
authors = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e"};
authors[6]="f";
```

More about arrays in java here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Yeah, I knew I was creating the array twice & I obviously don't want to do that, I was trying to work out where in the code to do the limiting to 5 and showed both my options - should've used comments rather than repeat the code.

So if I declare an empty array of 5 strings using: `private String[] actors = new String[5];`

How do I then populate it with up to 5 values using a constructor? Do I have to do something like:
    `actors[0] = "John"; actors[1] = "Paul";`

Can I not populate it in one line using something like:
`actors = {"John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "Dave"};`

Comment: best solution for your problem is given by @Bohemian, in the comments, it is also explained how to restrict that by adding a condition to check length of the argument and thrown an exception if it does not match your condition

Answer (score 2):

Use a *varargs* for the actors:

```
public Film(String title, double budget, String... actors) {
    this.title = title;
    this.budget = budget;
    this.actors = actors;
}
```

Then you can create a new Film with any number of actors:

```
Film a = new Film("Foo", 1.1, "Ringo");
Film b = new Film("Bar", 1.1, "Ringo", "John", "Paul");
```

Delete the default constructor - it serves no useful purpose.
Don’t declare the array for the field; just code `String[] actors;`

Comment: I understand about the default constructor but I'm doing this as part of an exercise and that's part of my task. If I use varargs as you suggested, how do I limit the length of the array to 5?

Comment: @Bongo there are two main ways to limit it to five: 1) check the length of the `actors` parameter in the constructor and throw an exception if it's longer than five, 2) don't use varargs and instead create five constructors that take 1,2,3,4 and 5 `String` parameters for actors

Answer (score 1):

you must add semicolon ; after   `budget = 1.1`

you have no variable called `authors` , perhapse you mean `actors`?

you cannot initialize a string array like

> ("McCauley", "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo")

it must be `new String[]{"McCauley", "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"}`

i suggest you use an IDE like eclipse or netbeans, as it can give you a clue to all of these issues and how to fix them

EDIT based on OP question about limiting to 5:
if you want to limit to 5 you can either :

1. pass each name as a separate argument and populate the array in the
   constructor
2. accept any size array and only populate the first 5
3. validate by throwing an exception if array of size more than 5 is
   passed

Comment: Yup, apologies for the missing ; and the actors/authors, that was an oversight on my behalf when dumping the code into here but not one that is reflected in my actual code. Anyhoo, using `new String[]{"McCauley"}` creates a new array which won't be limited to 5 values. And I'm using eclipse.

Comment: @Bongo except you won't be using new String[]{"McCauley"} you should be using new String[]{"McCauley", "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"}, or do you mean you need to pass the constructor any given number of names and not 5 excatly? please check my edit

Comment: Thanks @user1 Option 3 sounds the better one to fit with how I need it to work. In which case I assume I can just declare the array by using `private String[] actors;` and then populate the array using constructors. Can you please give me a steer on throwing an exception if >5 values are passed in?

Comment: @Bongo if (array.length>5) throw new Exception("message");

Answer (score 1):

you should instantiate your Film class as following:

`Film film = new Film("Movie", 10.00, new String[]{"a", "b", "c","d","e"});`

This because you want to pass an array to the Film constructor.

As for adding actors to a movie, you could add a function to the film class which verifies that the that there is a free spot, and if this is the case add it on the free spot.

Comment: But won't that create a new array that isn't limited to 5 values?

Comment: No it will create an array with a length based on the declaration